# Highmaps with US States in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to add a widget in my rails application, in which i am going to display the US states maps as given Demo [here in highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/color-axis)

The app is using `highcharts-rails` gem of version `4.0.4`, to display some other charts in the application. To use the maps, i am trying to include the js files from gem in `application.js` file as follows.

```
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/modules/data
//= require highcharts/modules/map
```

and also the JS file for loading states information in `application.html.erb`

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
```

I am able to get the state codes `Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all']` and also constructed the `data` from application as required. But the map is not displaying any thing and not seeing any errors in the `console` also.

But when i remove the including lines from `application.js` file and add the Java Script files explicitly, the map is loading perfectly without any issues. The below are the two js files that i am adding in my layout.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
```

Any help, why it is not loading the maps when i include the files through gem ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like gem is including too old version of maps, see version of the file on the [github](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/highcharts/modules) - it's 10months old :) Try to replace that file with [this one](http://github.highcharts.com/modules/map.src.js).

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus. I found that and fixed the issue. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to make it work with the gem itself, but i have to explicitly include the

```
//= require highcharts/modules/map
```

with the file that is available in http://www.highcharts.com/download for highmaps plugin, available in `Highmaps-1.0.4/js/modules/map.src.js`

Check the issue in [github](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails/issues/21#issuecomment-63490220)