# Rails and High Charts - can't render the maps at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, highmaps

I am having problems even getting off the ground with Highcharts maps.

I followed the rails installation.

Gemfile

```
      gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
```

application.js

```
  //= require highcharts
  //= require highcharts/highcharts-more
  //= require highcharts/modules/data
  //= require highcharts/modules/map
```

In my page

```
  <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>

  $(function () {

    // Prepare demo data
    var data = [{
        'hc-key': 'us',
        value: 3
    }, {
        'hc-key': 'ca',
        value: 5
    }, {
        'hc-key': 'mx',
        value: 20
    }];


    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

        title: {
            text: 'Showing only non-null areas'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'The <em>allAreas</em> option is false'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        series: [{
            data: data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/north-america-no-central'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            allAreas: false,
            name: 'Random data',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
          }]
        });
      });

   </script>
```

As you can see from the screenshot, there is no map rendered.

I have seen a similar question here:

[Highmaps with US States in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988456/highmaps-with-us-states-in-rails)

but I have tried these permutations and combinations of placing the links to the js files in my application header without success. The simple "your first chart" installation in the docs works fine

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

.....as soon as I try maps, no joy.

[image: Screen shot = no map rendered]

EDIT

So,

if i remove the files from application.js and add

```
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

to my application header....the following works..

```
      <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


  <script>
    $(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Add lower case codes to the data set for inclusion in the tooltip.pointFormat
        $.each(data, function () {
            this.flag = this.code.replace('UK', 'GB').toLowerCase();
        });

        // Initiate the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

            title: {
                text: 'Fixed tooltip with HTML'
            },

            legend: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Population density per km²',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                padding: 0,
                pointFormat: '<span class="f32"><span class="flag {point.flag}"></span></span>'
                + ' {point.name}: <b>{point.value}</b>/km²',
                positioner: function () {
                    return { x: 0, y: 250 };
                }
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                max: 1000,
                type: 'logarithmic'
            },

            series : [{
                data : data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                name: 'Population density',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                  }
               }]
             });
          });
      });
   </script>
```

Surely there has to be a nice "rails" way to get this working without explicitly calling the files in the header?

Comment: Where is **highmaps.js**? I can't see it in [documentation](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails)

Comment: I prefer using [lazy-highcharts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts). May be it helps.